# OneDrive for Business API: What is the Client Secret for a native app?

Tags: onedrive

According to the [API doc](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm), after you get an auth code in step 1 you need to redeem it for a token, using the following parameters:

client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_secret={client_secret}
&code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code&resource={resource_id}

But where do I get the client_secret value from? This is a native client app that I registered in Azure AD, so it only has a Client ID and a Redirect URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a native client app, you don't need to provide the client_secret value when redeeming the authorization code or refresh token. Only "confidential" clients, aka services, need to provide the client_secret.

Comment: Hey Ryan, long time no see! Thanks, but now I'm pulling my hair out over the construction of the final request. I'm getting an error 411: Length Required. Do the redirect_uri and resource parameters need to be encoded? But I tried with and without, same issue. Here's a sample request: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?client_id=12345678-dd63-436d-9be8-b033c6e4e128&redirect_uri=http://mydomain.onmicrosoft.com&code=AQABAAAAAADRNYR...&grant_type=authorization_code&resource=https://mydomain-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0

Comment: My ultimate goal is to either use the REST approach, or the SDK to read drives from multiple users with one admin account . I can login using the Explorer C# sample, but can't figure out how to access another user's drive that the logged in admin had permissions on. See: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/issues/42.

Comment: You need to build the request to the /token end point as a POST, and put the parameters into the body of the request, instead of putting them as query string parameters. That's mentioned here: https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm#step-2-redeem-the-authorization-code-for-tokens

Comment: AHA, thanks! BTW, I opened up a new question for my SDK issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232058/accessing-another-users-drive-using-the-onedrive-sdk