# Accessing another user's drive using the OneDrive SDK

Tags: onedrive

I can't figure out the proper syntax to open another user's OneDrive folder. What am I doing wrong? The parameter is supposed to be "ID", but is that a user ID/name, a drive ID - what? Below is some pseudo-code, based on the [OneDrive API Browser sample.](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sample-apibrowser-dotnet)

I get this error: "The provided drive id appears to be malformed, or does not represent a valid drive."

```cs
private async Task LoadUserDriveTest()
{
    Item folder;
    var expandValue = "thumbnails,children";

    folder =
        await oneDriveClient
        .Drives[$"user_mydomain_onmicrosoft_com"]
        .Root
        .Request()
        .Expand(expandValue)
        .GetAsync();
    //Code: invalidRequest
    //Message: The provided drive id appears to be malformed, or does not represent a valid drive.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a drive identifier, you can use any of these:

- User's UPN address (usera@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com)
- User's object ID in AAD (guid)
- DriveID previously obtained by other means (say, by having a shared item return a parentReference property with a driveID).

You'd think I would have [documented that here](https://dev.onedrive.com/drives/get.htm), but apparently I need to do some more writing.